# Ruby - Is storing a password as a variable safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, password-protection

I am building a blog web app in Rails, and since I need only one password, is it safe to store that password as a simple ruby variable e.g. `password = "foobar"`? Or should I put it in a database with proper password hashing?

Keep in mind that this is just a *single* password I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

Storing passwords is never "safe" ever even if they are hashed and in a DB. I would highly recommend against this as if anyone got access to the server or even the code they could very easily get your password. Furthermore don't write your own password hashing code, minute mistakes could seriously compromise your security.

My suggestion? Use Google or another OAuth provider, that way all you have to do is trust that google is right. This removes the burden of doing passwords right from you.

Comment: Not only is doing passwords yourself a burden, but very dangerous too. Especially for users who use the same password everywhere.

Comment: "all you have to do is trust that google is right". That's a big leap of faith right there.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a user model or even relying on a library like devise seems to be over kill in your case. Simple http auth should be good enough here. As per your question as to whether or not this is considered secure, it depends. If you're the only one with source code access (e.g. no github public repo; your machine is encrypted in case it is lost), you are using SSL & an HSTS header (to prevent SSL stripping) to communicate with your site, and you're using secret keys to access your server (i.e. no ssh login), then i think you're probably ok.

Here is an example of http auth in rails 4.0

`$ http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret"`

For example, the product controller would look as such:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index

   def index
     render text: "Everyone can see me!"
   end

   def edit
     render text: "I'm only accessible if you know the password"
   end
end
```

Find more examples [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

Comment: I couldn't disagree more, particularly with the large number of nginx and apache zero-days that have been going around lately there is no guarantee that the source is safe. More to the point you're assuming they are not using shared hosting, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: well zero-days usually mean all bets are off anyway. Same goes for crypto. I do like the idea of relying on a third-party oauth provider.

Comment: Point taken, if they have access to your server then they have access to your code and can modify it as they wish. At that point you're just in a state of mitigation. So obfuscating your password isn't going to do much anyway.